# Non-English badge notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications

I just got a badge on [Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tour), which is super cool! Except, well, because I am bad with many non-English languages, I am not entirely sure which badge it is.

[image]

I am guessing that might be Portuguese. Is there a reason this is showing up in my notifications like this?

Comment: So the bug is that the notification should have been in Klingon, right?

Comment: +1 for hand-drawn circles.

Comment: As for what badge it is, your profile says that "Nice Question" was the last badge, and that makes sense; I can't read the text either, but it does look like that question in the notification went from +9 to +10 right around when you posted this question.

Comment: For some reason, it's taking the badge data from http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question (so it's in Português)

Comment: Folks at [pt.so] are so excited that the question always pops "when we'll have other stack sites in Portuguese", well, looks like sooner rather than later :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Somebody at SE thought "pt" was short for "pets"? ;)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen you know, it might be true!

Comment: Can you repro? I see the English version in your list at the moment.

Comment: It disappeared, but other people have reported the same thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This bug was a race condition in our badge name/description caches.  These strings are cached per-site, on each web server.

What normally happens is, a badge is viewed on its owning site, so the language rendering matches, e.g. English badge names on English sites.

However, in this particular case, a http://pt.stackoverflow.com user viewed their topbar/achievements on the Portuguese site, and they had a badge on http://pets.stackexchange.com !  This incorrectly cached Portuguese badge names for an English site (but only on one web server).

The fix is to explicitly pass in the proper locale when rendering badges.

Comment: the bug (or a similar one) has struck again over at CodeGolf.SE: [Why are some of our badges in Portuguese?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/why-are-some-of-our-badges-in-portuguese)

Comment: @Jarrod [another one for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241900/how-comes-is-the-yearling-badge-displayed-in-portuguese-aniversariante). :)

Comment: I've pushed a refactoring of how badges are cached for a given locale; please let me know if you see any more issues.

Comment: [Stricken again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422735/why-is-there-some-russian-text-in-achievement-notifications).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum sadly not relevant, Jarrod no longer works for SE and can't fix it again anymore.