# Badge internationalization fail

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page, internationalization

On Music.SE, my profile has one badge and tooltip (except the text "silver badge") in what appears to be Portuguese, and the rest are English.

[image]

Presumably this is unintentional?

Comment: There's a possibly related question about the notifications as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/non-english-badge-notification

Comment: @PeterJ I didn't catch that one in my search for duplicates.  Apparently, I need to try harder.

Comment: I wouldn't really say this is a dupe, might be worth the developers knowing it happens on another site / page etc.

Comment: No repro now, I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k8s8q.png). Do you still see the different name? If so, it's only when viewing own profile. Weird anyway! :/

Comment: I see "Yearling". In english.

Comment: Basically, this happened once, and I couldn't reproduce it after that.  Since the linked answer says it's a race condition, that makes some sense.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235277/3

A fix will be pushed out shortly.

Comment: A link-only answer, Jarrod? For _shame_.