# New question badges on Stack Overflow em Português are in English

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, internationalization, portuguese-stackoverflow

"Curious", "Inquisitive", "Socratic" and its descriptions are in English on Stack Overflow em Português (I don't participate there myself, simply noticed).

[image]

I think it should be fixed.

Comment: Perhaps it's by design, so that to fully appreciate the curious badge you have to work out to translate it back from English to Portugese?

Comment: Voting to leave this open. This is a l10n issue (a Localisation issue), and just because there is only one localised site so far, does not make this site specific.

Comment: Wow, so with all those Portuguese language badges reported on other sites, the one Portuguese site gets English badges? That's where they went!

Comment: @MartijnPieters May I know what is "voting to leave this open"? You can vote to reopen before it closes? You mean that you decrease number of close votes by this vote?

Comment: @nicael: In the close vote review queue you have the option to *Leave Open*, next adding another close vote or skipping. Enough such *Leave Open* votes cause the post to be removed from the review queue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got it, thx.

Comment: It's ironic that whilst it's showing in English on Stackoverflow em Português, [it's showing as portugese on other sites ;)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/non-english-badge-notification) ... well aware that it's different localized strings, but still fun non-the-less :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with how badge names were being cached - see my answer here: [Non-english Badge Notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/non-english-badge-notification/235277#235277)