# How comes is the "yearling" badge displayed in Portuguese ("Aniversariante")?

Tags: bug, badges, localization

I was going through one of my SE [profiles](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/7654/franck-dernoncourt) to access some contents I posted and saw:

> [image]
>
> [image]

How comes?

---

It seems to only affects my profile on https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Odd. Displays in English for me...

Comment: Caching. [It's always caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/non-english-badge-notification).

Comment: I've pushed a refactoring of how badges are cached for a given locale; please let me know if you see any more issues.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Thanks, will do.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Just came across this post - probably needs [tag:status-completed] on it ;)