# I earned the Boa resposta badge!

Tags: bug, notifications, localization

It seems like on every site I click on Achievements (*except Meta.SE/SO*), it shows that I earned the *Boa resposta* badge. On meta.Se/So it shows I earned the *Good Answer* badge.

This appears to be a bug showing this badge in Portuguese language instead of the English language. This is the first time it's happened to me. All other older achievements show correctly.

[image: portuguese notification]

Comment: Parabéns!​​​​​​​ . . . . "Dupe": [Portuguese notification on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274512/1287812)

Comment: Well, seem like a bug reborn, I found a possible duplicate here, but it's marked `[status-completed]`: [Non-english Badge Notification?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234589/185667)

Comment: *"localization: not for the faint of heart"*

Comment: This is by design: SE will gradually  plant  more Portuguese terms around the sites. [They admitted it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/): "we have a plan: **Eventually, all of you are going to have to learn Portuguese.**"

Comment: [The return of the Bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/non-english-badge-notification)

Comment: I've pushed a refactoring of how badges are cached for a given locale; please let me know if you see any more issues.

Comment: close voters: when someone reports a bug and then it gets fixed, I don't think closing as offtopic/norepro is correct. It should get a status-completed tag maybe. This isn't "don't know what you're talking about that doesn't happen for anyone else" - this is "oops sorry fixed it."