# Eu não leio português: some of my badges are not in English

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

On Pets I am currently seeing a mix of English and Portuguese badges on [my profile](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/31/monica-cellio):

[image: badges]

This is true on the badges pages too -- the one listing all my badges, and the badge-specific pages that show all users who have the badge.

I do not see this for the same badges on other sites (I checked Yearling on MSE just now).  I checked some [other users with one of these badges on Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling) and others show the language change too; it appears to be something about specific badges on this specific site.

I'm aware of [this question about Portuguese notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234589/162102) (also from Pets).  It was reported to be fixed.  Looks like either it broke again or the notifications fix needs to be applied elsewhere on the site too.  (I note that it was reported as fixed in *July*, and I *think* I would have noticed this before if it'd been like this all along.)

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't for me, strange. Did you visit SO.pt before you reached pets?

Comment: I'm working on this now - it's part of a big refactoring of badge localization.

Comment: @rene no I haven't visited SO.pt in this browser at all.

Comment: Looks like the race condition still happens sometimes.

Comment: I've pushed a refactoring of how badges are cached for a given locale; please let me know if you see any more issues.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Dunno if [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250194/portuguese-tab-names-on-profile-page) is the same thing, but something similar has definitely popped up again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not seen this since Jarrod pushed this [fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242769/eu-n%c3%a3o-leio-portugu%c3%aas-some-of-my-badges-are-not-in-english#comment794205_242769):

> I've pushed a refactoring of how badges are cached for a given locale; please let me know if you see any more issues.  – Jarrod Dixon♦ Nov 3 '14 at 5:40

I think we can mark this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now.

Comment: Perhaps you’ve secretly learned to read Portuguese and so don’t notice it any longer. :)

Comment: @tchrist that's some secret!  We need to figure out how that works so I can repeat it with other languages.