# Portuguese tab names on profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization

A few minutes ago, when I viewed profile pages on my phone, the tabs were all in Portuguese:

1. On the mobile interface:

   [image: mobile interface screen shot]
2. On the full site

   [image]

But it didn't happen on my desktop, and now it's back to normal.  Other users report that the site is normal, but [Seth](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth) says it's still happening, so I've decided to post this bug report even though it seems to be working for me at the moment.   Perhaps it's some sort of intermittent problem.

I'm posting this on Meta.SE, since it seemed to happen on both Japanese.SE and ELL.SE, so it doesn't seem to be specific to a particular site.

Comment: I reproduced on 3 different sites, Unix and Linux, Software Recommendations and Stack Overflow. Running Firefox 35.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: I'm also seeing this across several SE sites.  Desktop, Windows 7, Chrome 39.0.2171.95

Comment: Ironically related: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2486/partes-da-p%C3%A1gina-de-usu%C3%A1rio-em-ingl%C3%AAs

Comment: Possibly related (and see links there): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242769/162102

Comment: Happens on [CommunityBuilding.se] as well: http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/why-are-these-tabs-in-not-in-english

Comment: Happens to me on SO and CR as well right now.

Comment: Also related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286931/692942

Comment: Reported on TeX.SE as well: [chat link 1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20252551#20252551), [chat link 2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20260829#20260829)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be fixed now... Probably. :)

We keep finding issues related to localization. In this case, it was a fun race condition to see which site would be hit first on a given web server after a production build and potentially populate a dictionary with strings from a non-English locale.

Jarrod pushed out a fix yesterday, so it shouldn't be happening any more.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I guess [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286931/the-tabs-on-the-user-profile-pages-are-showing-up-in-portuguese) can be marked as [status-completed] too, then.