# Wrong language in recent achievements

Tags: bug, status-review, achievements-dialog, languages

The "Achievements" menu on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour) shows me Russian text near my achievements:

[image]

The Russian text is:

> Узнайте больше об этом в Справке

Which [means](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%20%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5&op=translate):

> Learn more about it in Help.

I have checked my profile, and nowhere have I seen any country information or language preference. The [help center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=%20language) doesn't to have any information about changing the language of achievements.

I'm located in Germany, and https://www.myip.com/ agrees that my IP address is located in Germany. I don't speak Russian, and my browser doesn't have anything set to "Russian". Thus, I don't see why this text is in Russian. Also, even if Stack Exchange thought I was in Russia, it's a bit weird to have half of the text in Russian and the other half in English...

Comment: This is a rare case, the core issue was never fixed. [Here is one of the older bug reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/non-english-badge-notification). TL;DR: someone on Stack Overflow in Russian viewed their badges right after code rebuild, and have account on Skeptics as well, so Skeptics cache was built in Russian.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron interesting, thanks! (it's also interesting the the bug report you linked is marked as "status-completed")

Comment: After fixing the current bug report will be marked as ["статус-завершено"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be/info)

Comment: It’s marked as “status-completed” because the core issue *was* fixed per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/non-english-badge-notification#comment794207_235277 . Whether the fix was wrong or whether this is a new bug, I can’t tell.

Comment: A user on one of the sites I moderate reported a very similar issue for an inbox notification about a post (not an achievement); seems likely the cause is the same.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard sounds like the cache has a problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Still happening. I just got the error: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7fvg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7fvg.png)

Comment: The rare case has [occurred again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386556/why-are-my-priviledges-returned-to-me-in-russian) @ShadowWizardChasingStars .

Comment: @W.O. these days SE is making lots of code changes so it's expected for the caches to be reset more often and for this odd bug to kick in as well. But "rare" in this aspect might also mean "less than daily". ;)

Comment: [Probably the same issue but from another point of view.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/176217)

Comment: This also happening into Spanish on PLDI (Programming Language Design and Implementation) and this really needs to get fixed. https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/is-something-configured-to-be-in-spanish https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGzYT.png

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch we don't have access to that question, the site is private beta, so it just redirects to the login page. Please post screenshot of the question instead, if relevant at all.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ but does it usually work and showing the translated text? If not, it's a different and "bigger" bug.

Comment: @Starship generally, when you want to share content that not everyone, or many people, don't have access to, better take a screenshot and share it instead of link to the content. (Can be Stack Exchange post, or anything else e.g. something behind a paywall.)

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch for instance, you can upload an image in any post editor (but not save), copy the link to uploaded image, and then put it in any comment in form `[`name`](`link`)`. See [comment formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for details.

Answer (score 11):

I experienced this earlier when I joined the [Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com) community and answered a question.

[image: Achievements drop down displaying text in Russian instead of English]

(**Note:** I wasn't sure if this should have been a comment on the original question, rather than an answer, but I don't have sufficient rep to comment and I thought that attaching the image may be useful - apologies if this was not the ideal approach!)

Answer (score 8):

This problem is not fixed. I experienced it just now:

[image: You've earned the "Edit questions and answers" privilege! Узнайте больше об этом в Справке.]

Comment: OK, really no need to post new answer for any site where it happens. It's just noise. [One time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383029/152859) is fine, after a while, but two, in difference of a minute, is already pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Repeating my observations from [my Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424894/half-of-the-new-privilege-message-is-in-a-language-i-dont-speak):

First, this bug still exists in 2023 so it's over a year old at this point (or perhaps it was fixed and now it's back):
[image]

However, this bug only happens on main sites. When I switch over to meta it goes away:
[image]