# Why are the saves categories in wrong language?

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, saves

On https://stackoverflow.com, when I go to my profile to the tab "Saves" it looks like this:

[image: Saves tab open, showing Cyrillic script]

Strangely the tabs "For later" and "All saves" are in Russian.

> На потом

I don't use a translator, I don't live in Russia, and I don't have a VPN on or anything that could cause this.

Why is it like this? Does anyone else experience this problem?

**Browser:** Chrome Version 108.0.5359.99

Comment: That happens because the first user to hit Saves after a cache reset (server side) was in Russian.SO so the whole cache was built based on that. It's happening a lot in the inbox, where the captions are in some random non-English language so it's just natural they use the same mechanism for Saves. (They just assume the first user will be in main SO.)

Comment: Same with Safari on macOS. The bug is on all sites, not only SO.

Comment: Related/dupe: [Wrong language in recent achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376522/wrong-language-in-recent-achievements)

Comment: No repro in North America.

Comment: No repro at about 2022-12-11T141500Z+0. Fixed by now?

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum there are several servers, it affects only those who are served by the server with the "bad" cache.

Comment: a new hit in Taiwan [Space SE: "Question saved to На потом." Why is "for later" shown in Russian? Glitch in the Matrix?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385045/303080)

Comment: Semi-related, but the other side of things: ["All saves", "For later" and "View answer" (in the interface of the saves) are not translated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384251/335251)

Comment: My report, involving AskUbuntu, just now, is on its way to get closed, but hopefully I can save it by preserving this URL: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385784/908360

Comment: @Levente posts closed as duplicates never get automatically deleted. They are preserved as sign-posts. Deletion only happens when high-rep users think the sign-post isn't adding any value in sign-posting.

Comment: On Stack Overflow en espanol the Saves menu is all in English https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZfsI.png

Comment: I seem to gather the conclusion that websiting is hard. Thanks for the insight. :)

Comment: Just encountered this on SO, though for some reason I'm only seeing this on desktop (firefox/chrome) and not mobile (safari) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Yeg.png

Comment: @Adam any updates? It [happened again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386852/). Probably also related to other bugs where things showing in wrong language, so can kill several bugs in one fix.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I imagine it'll keep happening until the bug is fixed. :) I don't have any updates except to say that the bug's on the team's backlog. The reason the issue is intermittent is that there's a race condition which English wins most of the time. (But then other sites are showing English instead of their local language.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! We deployed a fix for this yesterday and it should be fixed. However, I'm not able to reproduce this issue either locally or in production. So it'll be hard for me to verify the fix. If it's still happening, please let us know.