# Bug: UI strings with mixed localization in popup message

Tags: bug, localization, saves

On [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour) I bookmarked a question ("saved for later"?), and the popping-up green notification message contains text with mixed locales: English mixed with some Cyrillic text; please. See the screenshot below:

[image: A screenshot of a notification message with mixed localization]

Comment: @toolic thank you, a `status-completed` tag could have answered it better, but yeah, yours is not bad either :D :thumbsup:

Comment: How can I put nicely rendered tags in my comments? I seem to remember it was possible. I crave the ability to drop fancy tags.

Comment: @Levente Unfortunately, those fancy red tags are moderator-only tags. Well, more specifically, they're Staff and Moderator-only. Only those with a staff or mod badge can edit them in.

Comment: Also, this bug isn't actually fixed yet, so a [tag:status-completed] tag would not be appropriate.