# Why are my privileges returned to me in Russian?

Tags: support, notifications, privileges, languages

I noticed I received a new privilege. However, this was the notification I got:

[image]

> You've earned the "Vote down" privilege! Узнайте больше об этом в Справке.

Why is the message in Russian?

Comment: okay, it makes me feel better, anytime I see thing like this I think the worst case scenario, and that I've been using a compromised computer and somones routing my traffic through russian or something LOL

Comment: All our computers are compromised and all traffic is seen by Putin. Beyond that everything is fine ...