# SE is showing 2 messages about bookmark/save in Russian (На потом and Все закладки)

Tags: bug, bookmarks, languages, saves

SE is showing 2 messages in Russian. [Example](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/saves/5656) from Money SE (grey boxes added for privacy):

[image]

Same issue without dark mode, on DS SE:

[image]

I'm located in the US, so there's no reason to localize to Russian.

Translations:

- Все закладки = All bookmarks
- На потом = For later

I see Russian on DS, Money and Travel SE. I don't see Russian on Meta SE. I use Chrome + Windows 10.

Comment: The example is a page only you can see .-.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek try with your profile. Same pb on the 2 SE I tried.

Comment: Its english to me

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Can you try on Money or Travel SE?

Comment: Probably related: [Wrong language in recent achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376522)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyi6N.png no repro on my end. Dosen't mean its not a thing, just that I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thanks, interesting!

Comment: Just to be sure - it looks like you got a custom stylesheet or extension for dark mode. What happens when you turn it off?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek also in Russian when no dark mode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM3i2.png. I use Chrome's native dark mode.

Comment: Also on MSO: [Do anyone know why default list of saved items shows this text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423289)