# Half of my notification about earning a new privilege is in a different language

Tags: bug, notifications, privileges

I recently earned a the privilege to "Create tag synonyms" here on meta. However, the notification in my achievements inbox is half in English and half in what I believe is Russian.

[image: Half English, half Russian inbox message.]

I opened this message on Arqade, which is an English site, and the privilege is for me which is also an English site, so I have no idea why half of the message is in Russian.

Comment: Very old bug that was never fixed, let me find the dupe. Edit: well [it happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/non-english-badge-notification) (and many more) but all wrongly marked as completed, so not closing as duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry That seems to be from caching between sites with 2 different languages, however the site I got it on and the site I viewed it on are both English, so definitely related, but maybe not the same.

Comment: I don't think it's just for you, looks like the first user who viewed that notification after cache reset did it here on MSE, while having account in Russian language site.